# pgbench select uuid for custom scripts

Tags: postgresql, pgbench

I am trying to benchmark a custom dataset with pgbench.
all the records I want to select for have uuids as primary keys.
Unfortunately all the samples snipets select random records by using random() function - presumably for sequential PKs.

```
\set bid random(1, 1 * :scale)
\set tid random(1, 10 * :scale)
\set delta random(-5000, 5000)

BEGIN;
UPDATE pgbench_accounts SET abalance = abalance + :delta WHERE aid = :aid;
SELECT abalance FROM pgbench_accounts WHERE aid = :aid;
UPDATE pgbench_tellers SET tbalance = tbalance + :delta WHERE tid = :tid;
UPDATE pgbench_branches SET bbalance = bbalance + :delta WHERE bid = :bid;
INSERT INTO pgbench_history (tid, bid, aid, delta, mtime) VALUES (:tid, :bid, :aid, :delta, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
END;
```

I wonder if there is a way to select random uuids from the tables into a variable, that's not accounted for in the latency.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gen_random_uuid()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-uuid.html):

```
SELECT gen_random_uuid();
```

Since version 13 that is integrated into core PostgreSQL, for older version you have to install the extension pgcrypto first:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time. My issue is that I already have a bunch of records with uuid's and I want to pick from those. Without affecting the latency measurement. I tried with a sub-select, but it slows everything down by 2 orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

You can just order by random().  Suppose you wanted to pick a sample of 5 rows from a table; lets call it `ruuids`. Then just (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=fe11464cf1c675fcbf6ede29fed55db0));

```
select * 
  from ruuids 
 order by random()
 limit 5;
```